# Check if object exists at list index in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if an object exists at a specified index in a List in Visual Basic.
What I have is

```
Dim theList As New List(Of Integer)({1,2,3})
If theList.Item(3) = Nothing Then
    'some code to execute if there is nothing at position 3 in the list
```

But when I run the program I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, saying the index is out of range. Of course it is, the entire point was to see if it does or doesn't exist. If "= Nothing" is not the way to check if something exists at that index, what is?

I am in my Application Development class and we are working on Windows Forms Applications using Visual Studio 2017, if any of that matters.

Comment: You are checking position 4.  Use `Items.Count - 1` to determine your max index.

Comment: I think we've got a little confusion in the wording here. I _am_ trying to look at what you call position 4, and check if anything exists there, which there isn't. I suppose looking at if the count is less than the index I'm trying to look at could work, but what if I had a situation where I had a value for theList.Item(2) and theList.Item(4) but not theList.Item(3). Would such a thing be possible in Visual Basic?

Comment: That is not possible with the `List`, regardless of the language. Lists and arrays are continuous (e.g. a `Dictionary` is not). And they all can contain `Nothing` at some or at all positions, as long as the declared data type allows it. `(Of Integer)` does not allow `Nothing`, e.g. `Of(Integer?)` does, and it has nothing to do with number of elements.

Comment: If your check might be out-of-bounds, you might want to make a check before the crash to insure that it stays inbound or return false by default - so you can avoid the out-of-range exception.

Answer (score 4):

If you are checking a list of objects, you need to change two things.

1. The way to check for nothing is to use `Is Nothing`.
2. You can't even attempt to check items beyond the end of the list, so you must first check that the index you want to use is less than the number of items in the list'

You should change your code to

```
If theList.Items.Count > 3 AndAlso theList.Item(3) Is Nothing Then
    'some code to execute if there is nothing at position 3 in the list
End If
```

Note the use of `AndAlso` rather than `And` in the `If` statement. This is required because it ensures that the check on item 3 happens only if there are at least 4 items in the list.

Also note that, in the code you posted, the list is a `List(Of Integer)`. An `Integer` can never be `Nothing`, so the second part of you check is either not needed or you should be checking for `= 0` instead of `Is Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have a list you can only access members of the list, accessing an imaginary item outside of the bounds will result in the error you specified..  The integer datatype comparison to Nothing is a comparison to 0.  IMO this use of nothing is not ideal.  If you want nothing you might look at Nullable.  Here is some code to take a look at.

```
    Dim theList As New List(Of Integer)({0, 1, 2, 3})

    For idx As Integer = 0 To theList.Count - 1 'look at each item
        If theList.Item(idx) = Nothing Then
            Stop ' item is 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim i As Integer = Nothing ' i = 0

    'Dim theListN As New List(Of Integer?)({1, 2, 3, Nothing, 5})
    Dim theListN As New List(Of Nullable(Of Integer))({1, 2, 3, Nothing, 5, Nothing})
    For idx As Integer = 0 To theListN.Count - 1 'look at each item
        If theListN.Item(idx) Is Nothing Then
            'item is nothing, not 0
            Dim nullI As Nullable(Of Integer) = theListN.Item(idx)
            If Not nullI.HasValue Then Stop
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: This line: `Dim theListN As New List(Of Nullable(Of Integer))({1, 2, 3, Nothing, 5, Nothing})` is really on point for steve.